# Sign assemblies gives no error but does not sign in VS2013

Tags: .net, visual-studio, .net-assembly, digital-signature, strongname

I have two solutions, both of which have the check box checked to "Sign the assembly" on the Signing page of each project's property page.

Solution A signs all projects and has no issues. In fact, solution A complained that an assembly did not have a strong name and failed to build the final application assembly. I checked, and the digital signature was missing on that assembly.

That assembly was created in another solution, Solution B, and referenced in. I went to that solution and added in the same statements to sign the assembly. I also checked like in solution A to sign the click once manifest.

Solution B build with no issues, no warnings, and no errors. Visual Studio built the DLL and the accompanying test application. I cleaned the solution first, debug and release, and then built the solution, no digital signatures.

I purchased a digital certificate, which I selected using the browser. The digital certificate has a password and has a PFX extension.

Solution A asked me to enter the password for every project in the solution. I set every project to sign the assembly. Solution B never asked me for the password.

When I had issues, I thought to recreate the solution and the projects from scratch and just add the existing CS files to the solution. Basically, I recreated the project and solution files. That had the exact same result. I even compared the assembly information file, Project\AssemblyInfo.cs in both solution A and B and saw no real difference.

### UPDATE:

Per request, here is the output of the build window. Sadly, by default there is no verbose build information. I was hoping for that.

```
BuildVersionIncrement: Pre-build process : Completed
1>------ Build started: Project: SolutionB, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
1>  SolutionB -> F:\Projects\SolutionB\Versions\2014\SolutionB\bin\Release\SolutionB.dll
2>------ Build started: Project: TesterSolutionB, Configuration: Release Any CPU ------
2>  TesterSolutionB -> F:\Projects\SolutionB\Versions\2014\TesterSolutionB\bin\Release\TesterSolutionB.exe
========== Build: 2 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
BuildVersionIncrement: Post-build process : Completed
```

---

UPDATE 2: I am using C#.Net. One project is a class library and the other is a Winforms project. I selected .Net Framework 4.5.1.

---

What can be the cause and how do I fix the problem? Sadly, the output window does not show the verbose build detail.

Comment: Can you share the command-line that VS displays in the Build Output window?

Comment: Sure, see modified posting above. Sadly, unless you know of a different window than "Output" with "Build" selected in the dropdown list, there is no real helpful information. I too was hoping for a blow-by-blow commands with parameters issued, but no such luck. Is there another window?

Comment: I figured out how to get detailed build output. Question 1211841 explains it, basically Tools | Options | Projects and Solutions | Build and Run | and set last two dropdown lists. Details to follow.

Comment: The problem might be due to this line. I am investigating it now, just complex to understand the detailed build output. "1>Task "AssignTargetPath" skipped, due to false condition; ('@(_DeploymentBaseManifestWithTargetPath)'=='' and '%(None.Extension)'=='.manifest') was evaluated as (''=='' and '.pfx'=='.manifest')."

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out comparing the detailed build output from the working project to the nonworking project.

IMHO, I would flag this issue as a defect in Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 (and previous versions), as it is so not obvious. Somehow eons ago I realized what to do, but forgot now.

Anyways, I am missing the addition of a "Post-build event command line" entry in the "Build Events" tab of the project properties page. One would assume that specifying all the information on the Signing page that you do not have to do it again. Whatever.

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1A\Bin\signtool.exe" sign /f <path to pfx file> /p <mypassword> /t http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)"
```

Also, add a similar line for the other configurations. This addition makes the Signing tab useless.

Comment: The original source had a "if $(ConfigurationName) == Debug " in front, however I took that out, as the release build does not get a digital signature.